# SQLite database is not creating

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

SQLite database is not creating.
I have used a method `getwritabledatabase();` in main class, but only the log appears "Constructor is called" and then the application is closed.

Here is my code

```
table extends SQLiteOpenHelper class

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.SQLDataException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Table extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Hammas's Database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Hammas's Table";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String COLNAME = "Names";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COLNAME+" VARCHAR(255));";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+TABLE_NAME+"";
private static final String TAG = "Hammas";
private Context context;
public Table(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    Message.message(context,"Constructor is called");
    Log.i(TAG,"CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  {

      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
      Message.message(context, "onCreate is called");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    Message.message(context,"onUpgrade is called");
}
}
```

Message class is just for toast.
Here is mainClass

```
enter code here

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Table table;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

    table = new Table(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sql=  table.getReadableDatabase();


}
```

Comment: If the database file already exists, `onCreate()` won't be called again. If you have a "force close", please post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Can you browse the file system and see if the .db exists. It should be:

Comment: //data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases

Comment: that won't work as a table name

Comment: why are you using single quote and space in your table/database name ?

Comment: I tried for try catch block but it is giving this error   'Exception java.sql.SQLEXception is never thrown in corresponding try catch block  '

Comment: Actually i am using android studio so there is no option for DDMS for file exploring .. where is the option in android studio????

Comment: Yes the single qoutes in table and database name is the only problem.

Answer (score 2):

This string can't be processed **as is**

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Hammas's Table";
```

It needs to be modified as

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "[Hammas''s Table]";
```

Because

- The apostrophe is a **string delimiter**, so it has to be doubled.
- The space would **break** the table name, so it needs to be enclosed in square brackets (`[]`).

This is also true for column names.
To insert apostrophes in string values, it has to be doubled, too.

Comment: Yes this the only problem .you saved my alot of time

Comment: Fantastic. Now you can accept my answer, in order to remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file system to ensure:

```
//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/Hammas's Database.db
```

is created and located there. It won't create again if it already exists.